# add sub into vb.net happen connection strings property has not been initialized

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have found a lot of solution regarding *Connection Strings Property has not been initialized*, I have try to follow and checking all the solution but it still not able to fix my problems.

It happen while I add into the `Private Sub getdetails()`, if I remove the sub it will recover. It not happen to other private sub it only this.

```
Private Sub GetOrgLocEdit()
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim params As New Hashtable
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Try
        params.Clear()

        strsql = "SELECT c.MMC_States + ' - ' + c.MMC_Desti as Desti FROM [database].[dbo].[tbODS] o " & _
            " INNER JOIN [database].[dbo].tbODSMealMilageClaims c " & _
            " on o.ODS_destination = c.MMC_States + ' - ' + c.MMC_Desti " & _
            " where c.MMC_Company = @company and o.ODS_ID = @id order by c.MMC_States, c.MMC_Desti "

        params.Add("@company", ddlcompany.SelectedValue.Trim)
        params.Add("@id", txtId.Text.Trim)

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ddlOrgLoc.DataSource = dt
            ddlOrgLoc.DataTextField = "Desti"
            ddlOrgLoc.DataValueField = "Desti"
            ddlOrgLoc.DataBind()
        Else
            ddlOrgLoc.Items.Clear()
        End If

        common.execReaderGREEN(strsql, params, dt, common.txn)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Connection String:

```
<add name="ConnStringGREEN" connectionString="Data Source=servername;DATABASE=database;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=user;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

OpenConn Method:

```
Public Sub OpenConn()
    Try
        'Portal Connection===========
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnStringGREEN").ConnectionString
        If Not conn Is Nothing Then
            If conn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then
                conn.Open()
            End If
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Can't connect to Portal SQL Server!")
        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
   conn.ConnectionString = 
   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnStringGREEN")
```